# Problems with render fullcalendar v4

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have problems with the render of version 4. In version 3 it was done as follows:

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', NuevoEvento);
```

In the new version it says that it is like this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )*/
```

```js
$('#btnAgregar').click(function() {
  var NuevoEvento = {
    title: $('#txtEvento').val(),
    description: $('#txtEvento').val(),
    start: $('#txtFecha').val(),
  };

  calendar.addEvent({
    NuevoEvento
  });

  $('#registrarEvento').modal('toggle'); //cerrar modal
});
```

Comment: Try `calendar.addEvent(NuevoEvento);` instead of `calendar.addEvent({NuevoEvento});`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
calendar.addEvent({
    NuevoEvento
  });
```

to

```
calendar.addEvent(
    NuevoEvento
  );
```

(i.e. remove the `{` and `}`). Fullcalendar expects an event object with the properties at the top level. Your `NuevoEvento` variable is already an object in that format, correctly. By putting `{` and `}` around it when you add it, you're using JavaScript's object-literal syntax to wrap it up inside another object, and fullCalendar cannot undertand the structure of it.